# (Sequelize) Using A Model By Name Dynamically

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm wondering if it is possible with Sequelize to create the needed models and then use one based on a value received from a request. I've tried different means to accomplish this but not finding a working solution. I accept it may not exist. But if so, does anyone have ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Models = require('../models');

...

for (let modelName in tablesObj) {
  if (modelName == primaryTable) {
    Models.modelName.findAll()
    .then(results => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is in your loader in the `/models` directory. It can export an object of `Models` keyed by the model name.

**models/index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const sequelize = // your db connection

// object to hold all the models to export
const models = {};

// Read all the files from this dir and load the models
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .forEach((file) => {
      if (file !== path.basename(__filename) && file.endsWith('.js')) {
        const model = sequelize.import(
            path.join(__dirname, '/', file.replace(/\.js$/, ''))
        );
        models[model.name] = model;
      }
    });

/* anything else you want to do goes here */

// export the models
module.exports = models;
```

Now you can load the `models` and then access each one by the name.

**other.js**

```
const models = require('../models');

async function runQuery() {
  // access "modelName" model
  const result = await models.modelName.findByPk(1);
  // rest of your method
}
```

I usually take this a step further and load the `models` into the file that creates the Express app, then set the models to a property on the `app` and pass that around to routers.

**server.js**

```
const Express = require('express');
const models = require('./models');
const app = new Express();

app.model = (model) => models[model];
```

Now you can access your models like so:

```
// assuming the model name is "Widget"
const widget = await app.models('Widget').findOne(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @doublesharp. I'll follow up once I put this into action.

Comment: UPDATE: I did not add that I was working with Express routers as well, but when I applied your use of setting the models as a property on the _request_ with a router.use, it worked beautifully! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was no need to add/modify the `index.js` file. The `index.js` was already present inside models folder by default.

Below code `works for me!!`,

```
    const models = require("../../models");
    let modeName, runningModel;

    router.get('/api/:module', (req, res) => {

      modelName = (req.params.module)
      runningModel = models[modelName];

      runningModel.findAndCountAll({
        //your code goes here
      })
      .then(resutls => res.json(results)
      .catch(err => res.json(err);
    }
```

The following are the package and version used in my project

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"morgan": "^1.10.0",
"pg": "^8.2.1",
"sequelize": "^5.21.4",
"sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"
```